# Prevenir que el body se vaya arriba al hacer click en boton menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, scroll

necesito saber cómo hacer que cuando a haga click en el boton de menu y este se despliegue, se mantenga el body en la misma posicion de scroll y no se vaya arriba. Actualmente, tengo un menu que se expande un ancho concreto cuando se hace click. En el background se ve el body, pero este sube hasta arriba de la pagina cuando hago click. Me gustaría que se mantuviera en la misma posición del scroll. Por supuesto,este es un menu fijo, dado que si no esta pregunta no tendría ningún sentido.

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(".nav-mobile-toggle").click(function(){
          $("html,body").css("overflow","hidden");
          event.preventDefault();
        });
```

HTML

```
<div class="nav-mobile-toggle pt8" data-modal-id data-notification-link="nav-slide">
                    <div class="btn--menu">
                        <span class="h6 nombre">Menu</span>
                        <i class="icon-Align-Right icon icon--sm"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
<div class="notification pos-right pos-top nav-slide col-sm-4 col-xs-12 bg--primary-1" data-notification-link="nav-slide" data-animation="from-right" id="notification">
        <div class="nav-slide__content">
            <div class="pt104 text-left">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/">
                            <span class="h3">Inicio</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                     <li>
                         <a href="/el-despacho.php">
                            <span class="h3">El despacho</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/quienes-somos.php">
                            <span class="h3">
                                Quiénes somos
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/que-nos-diferencia.php">
                            <span class="h3">
                                Qué nos diferencia
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/lo-que-opinan.php">
                            <span class="h3">
                                Qué opinan de nosotros
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/areas-practica.php">
                            <span class="h3">Áreas de práctica</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/blog">
                            <span class="h3">Blog</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/contacto.php">
                            <span class="h3">Contacta con nosotros</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="pos-absolute pos-bottom menu-footer text-right">
                <p class="tel">
                    <a href="tel:917553448" style="text-decoration:none;">
                        917 553 448
                    </a>
                </p>
                <p class="mail">
                     <a href="mailto:consulta@lawyerlex.es" style="text-decoration:none;">
                        consulta@lawyerlex.es 
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Agradezco vuestra ayuda de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Hazlo de esta manera

```
$(".nav-mobile-toggle").click(function(event){
     $("html,body").css("overflow","hidden");
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Sigue llevano el body al top al hacer click en el menu.

Comment: @raul prueba con `.on('click')` -> `$(document).on('click', '.nav-mobile-toggle', function (e) {  e.preventDefault(); $("html,body").css("overflow","hidden"); });`